# I have two dataframes, df and df1, I want to check if df1 columns values is present in df columns and print the entire row of the df if present

Tags: python, pandas

first df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,2,3,4],
              'col2':[5,6,7,8],
              'col3':[9,10,11,12],
              'col4':[13,14,15,16]})
```

second df:

```
df1= pd.DataFrame({'col1':[4,5,12,10],
               'col2':[1,5,25,12]})
```

I used this :

```
mergged = pd.merge(df,df1, on=['col1'],how='inner')
```

print(mergged)

what I want to  be as output is compare both df's col1,col2 and if values were matching I want to display the whole record

Desired Output:

```
4 8 12 16
1 5 9 13
```

any ideas or help will be very helpful thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this by comparing the two columns using [`.isin()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html), like so:

```py
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2, 3, 4],
                    'col2': [5, 6, 7, 8],
                    'col3': [9, 10, 11, 12],
                    'col4': [13, 14, 15, 16]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [4, 5, 12, 10],
                    'col2': [1, 5, 25, 12]})

df3 = df1[df1["col1"].isin(df2["col1"])]
df4 = df1[df1["col2"].isin(df2["col2"])]

print(df3.values[0])
print(df4.values[0])
```

Outputs:

```
[ 4  8 12 16]
[ 1  5  9 13]
```

If you need to check all different combinations of columns I believe you would need to loop over the different combinations. E.g. `for col_name in df1.columns` would get you the column name as a string.

Comment: Thanks it worked